# Copying of comments in proto file doesn't work out?

Tags: grpc

I have a proto file which contains two services.

When I generate index.html file from it, I see that the comments of the rpc methods of first service gets copied to the rpc calls of second service.

But in my proto file, I have given different comments to the rpc methods of both the service. Can anyone tell me how i should fix it ?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: But I would recommend you look into [mcve] and further enhance your question, for example by giving some example file contents.

Comment: It would be useful to know what generator you are using to produce the .html file.